# ASP.NET 4.0: Is it possible to make some user control's child controls public without using FindControl or public properties?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, controls, public

I have a custom user control that contains text boxes, dropdowns, etc.  I need these controls to be public so that I can go like `ucEmployeeAddress.txtAddr1.Text` from outside the control.

I know that I can use public properties in the control that return an instance of the control inside or use FindControl to locate my control from outside the user control, but I don't want to do that due to excess code.

If there is no way to do what I want then I will just go the public property route.

**Edit: Would the person who thumbed my question down be so kind as to explain how my question shows lack of research effort, is unclear, or not useful?**

Comment: So you want to expose something as a property, without actually writing the code to expose it, because you dont want `excess` code... interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, about three hours later, I finally came upon a solution.  I don't know if this is new in VS2010, but you can actually edit the user control's designer and turn all members from Protected to Public.  I swear I've tried this with earlier versions of VS in the past without success, but it's apparently working for me now.

What's interesting is that the IDE has a keen sense of what parts of the designer it should and should not regenerate.  For example, if you comment out the entire contents of the designer class, it will not regenerate the commented-out members.  To get it to regenerate them, you have to completely delete the members that you want regenerated.  What's also cool is that you can comment out the entire designer class's contents, switch back to the markup and add a server control like a textbox, and flip back to the designer to discover that it generated the member definition for only that control while the rest of the member references remain commented-out.  **Edit**: And if you delete a control from the markup whose designer member you had modified from protected to public, it will still delete the reference from the designer.

I will note that I am also using VB.NET.  I would have to assume this works with C#, as well, but cannot say for sure.

Comment: That may work, but that's not the right way to do it. Just create properties to expose data, like in my example.

Comment: Your method is the last-resort method I mentioned at the end of my question.  I definitely don't want to do this the wrong way, so, before I make a final decision, can you go into more detail as to why my method is not the "right" way?  Do you mean that it's merely not a widely accepted solution or are there measurable implications for doing it this way?

Comment: Technically there's nothing wrong with the approach you mentioned, but standard practice is to use properties. Using properties allows you to control what information about the control is accessible, and choose meaninful and descriptive property names. For example, `MyUserControl.ContentTitle` looks a lot cleaner than `MyUserControl.txtSomeTitle.Text.Trim()`

Comment: I certainly agree with you on that.  In my case, though, I do need the actual instance of the control so I can pass its reference elsewhere.  It's very difficult to explain why I need to do this without creating a boring wall of text.

Comment: In that case, you can just create a property that exposes the control itself.

Comment: Which brings us back to the question of why altering the designer file in this fashion is improper.  In programming, there are certain practices that are not accepted simply because they don't adhere to certain subjective principles (variable naming conventions).  Other practices are simply crude and unconventional (goto statements, reusing variables).  Others violate best practice (repetitive code).  Others have measurable implications on your application (not closing connections).  Where would you classify modifying the designer file to make certain controls public?

Comment: I would say that it violates best practices and accepted design principles. This article explains it pretty well: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to expose the entire control ?

If its just the text property you could just expose that.

```
public string TitleText
{
     get { return this.txtTitle.Text;}
}
```

If you really need the control i would suggest exposing it via a property, consumers may not even know the existance or name of the control, and nor should they care about your internal workings - using `FindControl` is a poor solution from outside of the control.

```
public TextBox TitleTextBox
{
     get { return this.txtTitle;}
}
```

As an alternative you may be able to modify the visual studio templates to expose all your controls as public, however im not sure if this is such a great idea or how you would do it..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to expose a property in the user control:

```
public string Address
{
    get
    {
        return txtAddr1.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        txtAddr1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Want to make sure that is there a similar statement to `x:FieldModifier="public"` in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is through event bubbling. This way you can keep the implementation of your controls hidden while being able to modify the properties that you chose.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720044%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) does a good job explaining how to accomplish this.

*As a side note, you should be more concerned with the elegance of your code than the amount of it.*

If you take the time to implement event bubbling, for example, as opposed to exposing the control's children as `public`, any manipulation of the control's children is handled by that control. This makes it easy to maintain if ever the logic of manipulation were to change, and easy to implement across your entire application.

However, if you expose your control's children as `public` instead, you must repeat that manipulation everywhere it is used.

Therefore, the "excess code" will both improve the quality of your code and actually decrease this "excess code" you are concerned about.